# How to create a javascript mongodb-tutorial-like browser shell

Tags: shell, mongodb, browser

MongoDB website uses a "Browser Shell" to let anybody try how it works really easily. I would like to implement something like that for a site to let devs do some HTTP request for a REST API - how should I approach this? Is there a plugin or tool that I could use?

The mongoDB example can be found here: http://www.mongodb.org/# - click "Try It Out".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "mongulator" code, written by Kyle Banker, is what you want.  He talks about it here:

http://kylebanker.com/blog/2010/1/try-mongodb-browser/

You can see the code on github here:

https://github.com/banker/mongulator

There are also other similar non-MongoDB options available out there as examples - good hunting!

Comment: thanx alot for your answer @Adam C.Can you say me where i can get similar non-MongoDB options as examples?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Shell might be helpful 
http://www.springsource.org/spring-shell

Answer (score 0):

You can visit www.domongodb.com. I am sure you want like this an online mongodb shell to try actual mongodb commands. http://www.domongodb.com

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the interactive web shell on [try.mongodb.org](http://try.mongodb.org/) was discussed on the [MongoDB Blog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58228251389/the-mongodb-web-shell) with [code available on Github](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-web-shell).

Note that interactive shells in a web environment have some peculiar limitations (some of which are covered on the blog post) esp. surrounding activity which can block the browser thread.